# ReconcileDynamicAxis (reconcile_dynamic_axis) in CNTK 2.0 Python API

Tags: python, cntk

CNTK Brainscript provides function ReconcileDynamicAxis for dealing with multiple dynamic axes (e.g. multiple sequence inputs of different size). I didn't find any official documentation about similar Python API. Finally, following some code available on CNTK github, I figured out a way to use it:

`from _cntk_py import reconcile_dynamic_axis
[...]
reconciled_vector_A = typemap(reconcile_dynamic_axis)(vector_A, vector_B)`

...it seems to work, but it looks like it's some internal CNTK function and possibly wasn't intended for public use.

Is there a public API version of reconcile_dynamic_axis and if not, what is the recommended way of dealing with multiple dynamic axes in Python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sequence.broadcast_as](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.sequence.html#cntk.ops.sequence.broadcast_as) if you just want to convert non-sequence to sequence.